# MongoDB & Web API - can't understand how to use filters

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to do basic CRUD on a MongoDB using C# Web API. All the examples online are for deprecated methods and I simply can't get the new methods to work.

the places where i need help in the code bellow:

1. Delete all items in collection - syntax to remove all.
2. get all items in collection - filter for get all
3. get by id = syntax to select by id

i've tried many examples online. most are deprecated for previous versions of MongoDB and the official Mongo docs are not helping, i suspect as my code is involving WebAPI classes and the examples are not for that.

thanks for your help!

This is the class:

```
  public class template
{

    [BsonId]
    public string templateUniqueId { get; set; }

    public string outsideClientId { get; set; }

    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public string templateFieldsData { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; }

}
```

And my repository implementation (part of if):

```
public class templateRepository : ItemplateRepository
    {
        public MongoClient client;
        public IMongoDatabase database;
        public IMongoCollection<template> templatesCollection;
        public templateRepository()
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mongoconnection"];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
            {
                connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
            }

            client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            database = client.GetDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mongo_personal"]);

            templatesCollection = database.GetCollection<template>("templates");
            //var persons = await collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync();


            // Reset database and add some default entries
            FilterDefinition<template> f;

            var result = templatesCollection.DeleteMany(f); // this line should remove all items

            for (int index = 1; index < 5; index++)
            {
                template template1 = new template
                {
                    templateUniqueId = string.Format("t{0}", index.ToString()),
                    outsideClientId= string.Format("t{0}", index.ToString()),
                    ClientId = string.Format("t{0}", index.ToString()),
                    isActive = true,
                    templateFieldsData = "sharon"

                };
                AddTemplate(template1);
            }
        }

        public void AddTemplate(template templateIn)
        {
            database.GetCollection<template>("templates").InsertOne(templateIn);
        }

        public IEnumerable<template> GetAllTemplates()
        {
            var templates = database.GetCollection<template>("templates").Find({ }); // get all templates
            return templates;
        }


        public template GetTemplate(string id)
        {
            IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("_id", id);
            return templatesCollection.Find(query).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public bool UpdateTemplate(string id, template item)
        {
            IMongoQuery query = Query.EQ("_id", id);
            item.LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
            IMongoUpdate update = Update
                .Set("outsideClientId", item.outsideClientId)
               .Set("ClientId", item.ClientId)
                .Set("isActive", item.isActive)
               .Set("templateFieldsData", item.templateFieldsData);
            SafeModeResult result = templatesCollection.Update(query, update);
            return result.UpdatedExisting;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the legacy driver methods, here are some examples for [MongoDB C# Driver 2.2](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/):

**Delete all items in collection**, syntax to remove all.

```
coll.DeleteMany(FilterDefinition<template>.Empty);
```

**Get all items in collection**, filter for get all

```
var results = coll.Find(FilterDefinition<template>.Empty).ToList();
```

**Get by id**, syntax to select by id

```
var filter = Builders<template>.Filter.Eq(t=>t.templateUniqueId, id);
var result = coll.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, for your **update method**, you can use the following syntax:

```
var filter = Builders<template>.Filter.Eq(t=>t.templateUniqueId, id);
var update = Builders<template>.Update
    .Set(t=>t.outsideClientId, item.outsideClientId)
    .Set(t=>t.ClientId, item.ClientId)
    .Set(t=>t.isActive, item.isActive)
    .Set(t=>t.templateFieldsData, item.templateFieldsData);

var updateResult = coll.UpdateOne(filter, update);
return result.ModifiedCount > 0;
```

More information about Definitions and Builders:
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/

Comment: thanks! just a small remark the update syntax i used "UpdateOne" as Update is not available. - thanks!!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the warning, updated the answer accordingly :)